# Rails - How to serve different catalogues of images

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to serve different catalogues of images depends on actual app configuration. For example: for directory structure like the one below I would like to serve `img1.png` from `folder_1` or `folder_2` for request `myapp.com/images/img1.png` depends from actual configuration.

```
 - public
   - images
     - folder_1
       - img1.png
     - folder_2
       - img1.png
```

On one application I have used custom middleware, something like this -> `config.middleware.use "Rack::MyHandler"`. I have given a shot but I have quickly discovered that the request to files in public catalogue is not handled by it. Now the problem lies on that I would like to handle it as fast as possible, so the processing by controller is not the case. Probably running from Apache I would try `mod_rewrite`, maybe there is something for Rails? Any suggestions?

Comment: *depends on actual app configuration*, you say? Is it always a single folder for a single instance of an applicaiton, just multiple folders in the source code? The idea is, can you symlink it at deployment time?

Comment: Right now, I am setting the config on init so the symlink will do the job for this purpose. Thx

Comment: nevertheless for debugging it will be annoying to change it. Right now I have two instances of app running and untill now I could test everything I need, now I would need to remember to use symlink... hmmm... I am to lazy for that:-) So looking hopefully for another suggestion:-)

Comment: You can make a script that creates a symlink to the correct folder. You want it to be performant, so your best bet is filesystem level.

Comment: yes that is not a problem, actually I added it for Rails startup but like I said, till now I could have many instances of my app, each with different settings, they have nothing in common till the images came up:-) The best solution would be to set the symlink for WEBrick as each app starts on different instance but I doubt that there will be similar solution.

Comment: Carrierwave's default settings creates separate folders for images by models name. Each models name will have different folder which name is id of its model. Or you may set multiple uploaders for one model and each of these uploaders have folder settings. Then you create method which will return Image from uploader that will satisfy current settings.

Comment: I think that I could effort to create symlink for every request on development environment and on production it will be only on initialization:-)